# Create different ranges of bins based on a dataframe columns and get the count

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, data-manipulation

I am a bit newbie in Python. I have a dataframe with three columns as below-

[image]

I would like to divide the 'col1' into bins with range 2 and obtain the corresponding ranges(min,max values) for other two columns. Additionally, also wanted to know the number of records under these individual bins-

[image]

I tried using qcut for each column and obtain the result, but doesn't seem to obtain the valid results. The results doesn't necessarily need to have '[' but can be '(' too.

Also if the ranges for other two columns are unequal w.r.t the range of the first column, the last value in the current(other two columns) column can be repeated till the end.

Any help on how to create a new 'ranges' and 'countx' column will be appreciated.

Comment: do all columns share the same the same min/max threshold. I ask because one column might need more bins than another if that's not the case

Comment: please post the data as a copyable text. Images cannot be copied

Comment: @ksooklall, all columns do not have the same range of values. you're right, 1 column might need more bins than the other. Hence I mentioned - "Also if the ranges for other two columns are unequal w.r.t the range of the first column, the last value in the current(other two columns) column can be repeated till the end."

Comment: have you looked at my solution? You can concat them to a dataframe but you will have a lot of nans

Comment: @Ksoosklall, yes I tried your solution, doesn't quite give the output. You see I want to bin col1 with range=2 first, and check the other column values which are lying in this range of 'col1' and later get their ranges. Subsequently obtain the count (records) falling under this range.
My problem is more like price range estimation, one col for new prices, previous price and very old price. So my objective here is that I have generated new price and wanted to display what were the previous and old price ranges and how many records got impacted.

Comment: So your expecting to have 3 `count_records` columns? Since the 0-2 count can be different for each column

Comment: Based on my 'col1', I want to know the min-max range of values for other two columns and also the count of records lying the range of values corresponding to 'col1'. The above result is based on this calculation only.. The column 'col1' is expected in the bins with range 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by columns with `pd.cut`

First get the bins based on the largest

```
bins = [2*i for i in range(df['c1'].max()// 2+1)]

[0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

then apply the `cut`

```
df.apply(pd.cut, bins=bins)['c1'].value_counts()

(8, 10]    5
(2, 4]     5
(6, 8]     2
(4, 6]     2
(0, 2]     1
```